# Read Redshift external table in DBT

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

I was trying to read a **redshift external table** from **dbt** which I created by reading the data from s3 bucket. In DBT I created a .sql file in the models folder and wrote the below query.

{{ config(materialized="view") }}

select * from <<schema_name>>.<<table_name>>

But getting the following error:

**Operations on local objects in external schema are not enabled**

Need help !! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use the dbt package of macros: [dbt-external-tables](https://hub.getdbt.com/dbt-labs/dbt_external_tables/latest/). You can't read from S3 without it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Anders Swanson answer, once installed the library and configured the `.yml` file I run the following command:

```
dbt run-operation stage_external_sources --args "select: my_schema.my_table"
```

If it's necessary to recreate the external table the following option can help:

```
--vars "ext_full_refresh: true"
```